# Hook error in Route Container component using useParams

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am using a route like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import AdminBank from 'views/Bank/Bank';
import CustomerBank from 'views/CustomerBank/CustomerBank';

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({}, dispatch),
});

const BankContainer = (props) => {
  const { userType } = useParams();
  return (
    userType === "admin" ? <AdminBank/> : <CustomerBank/>
  )
}

export default connect(
  BankContainer,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BankContainer);
```

The Bank component is a redux container component. Inside I have a conditional render based off the user type.

```
const BankContainer = (props) => {
  const { userType } = useParams();
  return (
    userType === "admin" ? <Bank/> : <CustomerBank/>
  )
}
```

I get a react warning and then a react error

Warning:

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by ConnectFunction. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useMemo                    useMemo
2. useMemo                    useMemo
3. useContext                 useContext
4. useMemo                    useMemo
5. useMemo                    useMemo
6. useMemo                    useMemo
7. useReducer                 useReducer
8. useRef                     useRef
9. useRef                     useRef
10. useRef                    useRef
11. useRef                    useRef
12. useMemo                   useMemo
13. useContext                useLayoutEffect
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    in ConnectFunction (at Admin.js:68)
    in Route (at Admin.js:68)
    in Switch (at Admin.js:63)
    in div (at Admin.js:59)
    in Admin (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at ProtectedRoute.js:13)
    in Route (at ProtectedRoute.js:29)
    in ProtectedRoute (at ProtectedRoute.js:46)
    in ProtectedAdminRoute (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Main.js:46)
    in Switch (at Main.js:45)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at Main.js:44)
    in Main (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at src/index.js:63)
    in App (at src/index.js:69)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:68)
```

Error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

my package.json versions:

```
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
```

Thing's I've tried:

1. Checked for react bundler issues
2. Switched to view rather than just a react container
3. Tried other hooks, still same issue

Comment: it is unclear where you render `BankContainer`? is `BankContainer` the same as `Bank`?

Comment: My apologies, yes Bank and BankContainer are the same component.

Comment: Do you call `useLayoutEffect` anywhere?

Comment: Also `Bank` has redux's `Provider` in it ?

Comment: That's why I'm confused, I've never used that hook anywhere in this project. Just useEffect. I know the useContext comes from react-router. Not sure where the useLayoutEffect is coming from.

Comment: <Provider> component is surrounding my <App/> component.

Comment: Added full container code to original post, hopefully that makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: Ok, you are passing the `BankContainer` to  `mapStateToProps` argument of `connect` function which is definitely wrong

Comment: You don't even pull any state from the store in this component. You don't need connect here. Also consider using `useDispatch` and `useSelector` instead of connect if you can.

Comment: Ya I was setting up a container to pull from state but ya you're very right I setup the container completely wrong for whatever reason just for this one. Thanks so much that was the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `BankContainer` to `mapStateToProps` argument of connect function which is definitely wrong. You should something else...

Comment: Ya for sure, I just created a map function instead. I have no idea why I passed the component lol. Also will look into useSelector, thanks a bunch again

Comment: so eh... can you mark it as answer? also checkout redux hooks and redux toolkit, connect is sort of considered obsolete at this point.

Comment: oh ya my bad dude

Answer (score 1):

Hi as @ThatAnnoyingDude just say in the first answer this correct react-redux connect get 2 arguments and they are
mapStateToProps - bring you back as props the requested state from redux
mapDispatchToProps - bring you back as props the requested action from redux
if you don't want to pass one of them you should do like this:

```
export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BankContainer);
```

work the same for the second one.